# Tableview with Search Bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have been trying to implement a `UISearchBar` to filter(search) my `UITableView` since yesterday but no luck.

I added my `UISearchBar` to my header file like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>{
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *TableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *mySearchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredsarkilar;
@property BOOL isFiltered;
@end
```

I made my `UITableView`'s datasource a `NSDictionary` with indexes and sections which include titles and subtitles. It works exactly the way I want. Here is the implementation file which I have already tried to implement the search function. And by the way when I press search button the keyboard does not dismiss, why?

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController (){
    NSDictionary *sarkilar;
    NSArray *sarkilarSectionTitles;
    NSArray *sarkilarIndexTitles;
}
@end
@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize mySearchBar, filteredsarkilar, isFiltered;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newButton];

    sarkilar = @{
                 @"A" : @[@{@"title":@"Alayına İsyan",@"subtitle":@"Seslendiren: Mustafa Sandal"},
                        @{@"title":@"Ardindan",@"subtitle":@"Seslendiren: Sinasi Gurel"}],
                 @"B" : @[@{@"title":@"Birak Gitsin",@"subtitle":@"Seslendiren: Tarkan"},
                        @{@"title":@"Buralar",@"subtitle":@"Seslendiren: Duman"}],
                 @"C" : @[@{@"title":@"Cephaneler",@"subtitle":@"Seslendiren: Burak Kut"},
                          @{@"title":@"Cari Acik",@"subtitle":@"Seslendiren: Kristal"}],
                 };

    sarkilarSectionTitles = [[sarkilar allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    sarkilarIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C",@"Ç", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I",@"İ", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"Ö", @"P", @"R", @"S",@"Ş", @"T", @"U",@"Ü", @"V", @"Y", @"Z"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [sarkilarSectionTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        return filteredsarkilar.count;
    }
    else
    {

    NSString *sectionTitle = [sarkilarSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionSarkilar = [sarkilar objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionSarkilar count];
    }

}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [sarkilarSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *sectionTitle = [sarkilarSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionSarkilar = [sarkilar objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSDictionary *dict = [sectionSarkilar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *subtitle = [dict objectForKey:@"subtitle"];

    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        cell.textLabel.text  = title;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

    }
    else
    {
    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;
    }

    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return cell;

}


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sarkilarIndexTitles;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [sarkilarSectionTitles indexOfObject:title];
}


-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered =YES;
        filteredsarkilar = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        for (NSString *title in sarkilar)
        {
            NSRange titleRange = [title rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (titleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filteredsarkilar addObject:title];
            }
        }
    }
    [TableView reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
    DetailViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];

    destinationViewController.title = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
   }
}

@end
```

Please help me if you can, because I've been pulling my hair off my head!! Thank you
[image]

Comment: Try [yourTableViewIBoutletName reloadData]; instead of [UITableView load];

Comment: no luck, i have tried that already but no... i don't know why...

Comment: Are your -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText & -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar methods called correctly & filter the data to the array??

Comment: i think so, but i can not be sure that i am not missing anything...

Comment: try to add `[self.view endEditing:YES];` all views will resign first responder.

Comment: now it acts like it is filtering but, i can say it is not doing it properly. it filters every first title. when i type "a" it leaves the first titles of each section. when i "al" (like the one in the first cell - Alayina Isyan) everything dissapears. and the keyboard still does not dismiss after i hit search button. it is driving me crazy...